# Is there a way to normalize a vector such that it lives on a Poincare Disk?

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

If I have a vector, by normalizing its length I can make sure such vectors lives on a hypersphere.

Is there a way to do this for Poincare Disk or other hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: Strange question. What can we do with a **single** vector  ? You would have said: I have 3 points making a triangle in the euclidean plane, how can I associate them with a certain process a triangle in the Poincaré disk, I would have understood...

Comment: @JeanMarie you are right I could have formulated the question better. Should have said for any vector in a Euclidean space ...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric#Metric_and_volume_element_on_the_Poincar%C3%A9_disk for the metric and geodesics on the hyperbolic disk. The word vector has a different meaning in manifolds, it refers to tangent vectors, a direction at a base point, but its end is not another point of the manifold. A piece of geodesic is not a vector, you can't translate it to $(0,0)$ as in $\Bbb{R}^2$..

Comment: And the hyperbolic disk is not a sub Riemannian manifold of $\Bbb{R}^n$, because of the negative curvature, in contrary to the sphere and its positive curvature.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the open disk is homeomorphic to the Euclidean plane. I found my answer on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk).

Comment: Yes, the open disk is homeomorphic to the plane, but the Poincaré disk as a metric space is certainly not a vector space, so you cannot scale by scalar multiplication. You could draw a little circle centered at the origin of the Poincaré disk and then map any other point $x$ to the intersection of the unique geodesic ("straight line")  joining the origin and $x$ with that circle. But there's no "obvious" such little circle to choose.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your answer. I guess I did not formulate my question clearly. I just have vectors in euclidean space and I want to map them to a Poincare disk (don't even need bijection) so that function is what I need.